# .Net 5 - using System.Web - Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. (0x80131058)

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-5

I'm porting a .Net 4.5 Framework app to .Net 5 (I want to publish a single executable with `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true --self-contained true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesInSingleFile=true`).

I packaged dll into a NuGet package. This includes System.web.Services.dll (4.0.300319.18020, a .Net Framework 4.5 dll I think) along with it's dll.

[image: Nuget package reference]

This builds with a .csproj file of

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="ReportingServices2010" Version="1.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="SharpZipLib" Version="1.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

At run time, I get this:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (0x80131058)
File name: 'System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
```

I've been searching for awhile, but I haven't found a way around this. I think that .Net 5 can reference this directly, especially with `TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`. Why can't it load it? Why is the error message Version=4.0.0.0? Where is it attempting to load the dll from (is the GAC still something in .net 5?)

Comment: delete bin and obj folder, delete all nuget caches files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`, does the error persist?

Comment: the error persists. I'm curious, why might that have worked?

Comment: @AlignedDev I am having the same problem - migrating a .Net Framework 4.7.2 assembly to .NET 5.0 and getting the same error that HttpContext does not exist because System.Web is not in the SDK. This is a breaking change https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/authorization-resource-in-endpoint-routing. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @jWeezy I did not get this figured out. I ended up moving on to other things and didn't get this resolved.